# Probability that two random variables are equal

Tags: probability

A number $X$ is chosen at random from the series $2,5,8,\dots$ and another number $Y$ is chosen at random from the series $3,7,11,\dots$ Each series has 100 terms. Find $P(X=Y)$.

The answer is $\frac{25}{100^2}$, since there are 25 matching pairs of $(X,Y)$ out of $100^2$.

My attempt: $2+3n=3+4n$, which means $n=-1$, so a pair of $(X,Y)$ is equivalent if $n\equiv-1\mod3\wedge n\equiv-1\mod4\Leftrightarrow n\equiv-1\mod12$, so $X=Y$ if $n$ is of the form $n=12k-1$, but I don't see how this shows that there are 25 matching pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the system of congruences $z\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, $z\equiv 3\pmod{4}$. This has the solution $z\equiv 11\pmod{12}$.

Starting at the fourth term $11$ of the first sequence, every fourth element of that sequence is an element of the second sequence. There are $25$ multiples of $4$ from $4$ to $100$ (both inclusive).

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion that every 4th element in the first sequence is an element of the second sequence?

Comment: One way of saying it is that $2+3(k+4)=2+3k+12$. And by the first paragraph if you increase a "good number" (solution of the system of congruences) by $12$, you get the next solution of the system.